# Bash script to read directories from file and then cd into them failing

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a bash script on my Mac that reads the contents of a file, and uses each line it reads to assemble a path to then cd into it and do some commands in there. Here is the script I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
repo="$HOME/sp16-cs233"
cat file.txt | while read line
do
        cd $repo/$line
        #do some stuff here
done
```

The file contains names of folders that are located under the repo path. When I try to run this I get the following error:

```
wirelessprvnat-172-17-237-248:Honors adelejjeh$ ./script.sh 
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/albers3
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/jablum2
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/iwchen2
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/durg2
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/hgao17
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/agoel9
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/eshoag2
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/jinglim2
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/gluo2
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/ypark92
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/hequ2
: No such file or directorysers/adelejjeh/sp16-cs233/dssheph2
```

For some reason, when the script is running something wrong is happening to the paths. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.txt` has Windows line ending characters; the lines are terminated with `\r\n` (CR-LF) rather than just `\n`. Bash does not ignore the `\r` at the end of the line, which means that it will be part of the pathname passed to the `cd` command. As a result, that command will fail. In addition, the `\r` is included in the error message, which makes it harder to read.

Running `dos2unix` (or equivalent) on the list of directories should fix the problem.